# Inside the SPFx web part, how i can get the current site collection url inside the "SharePoint/assets/elements.xml"

Tags: development, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am working on an SPFx web part, which inject a custom css inside the site collection. Now i define the location of the custom css file inside the `ClientSideComponentProperties` inside the `SharePoint/assets/elements.xml` file as follow:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="InjectCss"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer"
        ClientSideComponentId="5a1fcffd-dfeb-4844-b478-1feb4325a5a7"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;cssurl&quot;:&quot;/sites/Intranet-DEV/customcss/custom.css&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

[image]

so in the above case the custom.css file will be located inside a site collection with this static url `https://ourtenat.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet-DEV/customcss/custom.css`.. but can i change the location of the file to be dynamically inside the current site collection (where the web part will be added) ? so on each site collection i will define a library named `customcss` and add the `custom.css` file inside it? is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just below your </ CustomAction > Tag and Above the </ Elements> tag declare a module,

```
<Module Name="StyleLibrary" Url="SiteAssets">
      <File Path="custom.css" Url="custom.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />      </Module>
```

That should put the file directly in the site collections site asset library, also install the app on the site collection and not on the root site collection.